# 7 segment display issue

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay

I had a 7 segment, 4 digit display hooked to a very large board with **et6226m** (similar to **tm1650**), so i decided to desolder and pack it by putting the driver in between the 12 pins of display. Tested it and with my mcu, it worked fine but with a twist and thats confusing me..

First 3digits work fine, i can write *8* on them but if i try to write 8 on 4th digit, display starts to malfunction (flickers, turnsoff etc).

I can however write 9 on the last (4th) digit, which means only one out of 7 leds on 4th digit have a problem (led E).

I tested it manually with both a multimeter and by applying small voltages (like 2) on pin DIG4 and E, it does light up so its not burnt and neither is there a short circuit.

I don't think i have bad connections given the tests i performed, what could possibly have caused it.(It was working fine before i performed surgery on it).

**Notes:**

- Wires I used were from old headphones, single thread copper wire coated with enamel(?)
- everything is hot glued, no risk of short circuits.
- i did removed a zenor(?) diode on pin dig4 thinking that it might be the one causing problems.

**Update:**

[**Datasheet**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsOu5.jpg)

[**Connections**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQI8l.jpg)

[**Lashup, You asked for it**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcgc0.jpg)

**Update2:** just noticed there were two capacitors connected between vcc and gnd that forgot to put inside my new design, can those missing capacitors cause this problem?

**Update3:** I rewired everything and problem persists but it does work properly on 3v now (maybe because of longer wires?) which means it have something to do with over-volatage on ic (datasheet says it can work on 5v) or my mcu not being able to provide enough amps to *that part only*, New Question, **Do I need a resistor and/or capacitor in there somewhere? If yes, what should values be?**

Comment: Maybe your power supply is marginal. Did you try 8111 as opposed to 8888?

Comment: As i mentioned, it was working fine before, i can still write 8889 but not 8888. @spehro

Comment: There is 1/27 more current required for 8888 compared to 8889. I'm asking  you if it's position dependent or not, and that does not clearly answer the question. 1118 vs. 8888 with your reverse way of numbering the digits.

Comment: Yes its position dependent (exactly the E part), i can leave first 3 digits blank and still fail to write 0 2 6 or 8, I can write 1 3 4 7 or 9

Comment: I guess we need a schematic then. And a clear photo of the lash-up.

Comment: Are E and DIG4 connections swapped over?

Comment: No, all connections are fine

Comment: It might be worth double checking. I see that E and Dig4 are at opposite ends of the display. Easy to get them swapped over with each other.

Comment: In that case, E of all the other digits should also be swapped hence its not

Comment: Are you able to turn the E segment off on the other 3 digits?

Comment: Yes, i can turn it on or off on other digits expect the 4th one, and i can manually turn E of 4th with a multimeter or small voltage, just not with the mcu through driver ic